# error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) shared ovject <library_name>.so not found

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, virtualbox

Using VirtualBox with Ubuntu 20LTS, and attempting to install and load R packages, getting the error:

```
error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
shared object <library_name>.so not found
```

Where <library_name> can be any of multiply libraries:

- rlang
- digest
- fs
- fansi

So the error looks like this:

```
error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
shared object digest.so not found
```

So far, uninstalled and reinstalled the packages with install.packages() and with sudo apt-get install r-cran-.

Currently cannot use devtools to install because it too fails to load with `require(devtools)` saying shared object `fs.so` (was) not found.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please* step back a second and start from the top with a clean installation of R.  The do

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-digest
```

and `library(digest)` *will* work. I do not recall if `fs` and `fansi` are available for 20.04 so you will have to come to terms with source installation but even that should be easy of you have `r-base-dev` installed.

Now, we generally *strongly* recommend you start from the [README for Ubuntu at the CRAN repo](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) and enable that repo. Then you get R 4.2.1.  If you read the part on '5000+ CRAN Packages' you can equally easily get CRAN binaries for 5000+ packages, including `fs` and `fansi` as `r-cran-*` binaries from the c2d4u.team repo.

Better still, I now support a project I call [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) which has *all* of CRAN for Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.  The installation is simple in five quick steps in a documented script (and detailed at [the README of r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/).  You then can do

```
  install.packages(c("digest", "fs", "fansi"))
```

in R and get binaries *in seconds* as the gif below shows.

[image]

Comment: You since edited your question, but `rlang` installs of course as easily -- that is the point of offering _all of CRAN_ as complete, ready-to-install, full-depedency resolved binaries.  All that said, installation from source should also work but from what you posted we cannot tell why it does not for you.  We offer a mailing list r-sig-debian for Debian and Ubuntu if you need more help:  https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking the time to help... I ran the script that is included in your instruction site, and getting `Error: cannot connect to the system package manager`

Comment: You may need to ensure that `bspm` (which we use) is installed as root. We recommend the one call `sudo Rscript -e 'install.packages("bspm")'`.  You may also need to enable `sudo` mode for `bspm`, see the docs.  Let us know if that works -- r2u has been used by many with success, on direct installations, in WSL2, via Docker, ...

Comment: Ran your docker `eddelbuettel/r2u` and it worked great! A real life saver. Not sure why nothing was installing correctly on a fresh install of Ubuntu. Now need to get mxnet running :D

Comment: Glad it helped!  The commands creating / setting up the Dockerfile are at the repo, as is the helper script. I know we now may need to set a 'seccomp' (security policy) for some Docker uses to be allowed to pass commands from R to the system (using `bspm`). Maybe your VM needs an extra step too? I just don't know.  But either way you have the apt repository so there is always `sudo apt install r-cran-digest r-cran-rlang` and so on.

Comment: The r2u docker worked and saved the project... the apt repository didn't work on the VM (twice on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20&22). Thank you so much for helping and directing me to that great solution your created. It really made a huge difference as for some obscure reason, nothing worked on a fresh install and I imagine that even with the rocker docker, it could have worked but probably not nearly as fast as this amazing project.

Comment: If you want, and think have a chance at helping debug, we could try to look into _why_ the VM did not work. Can you open an issue at the GitHub repo?  Or if you think you can't or don't have time, no worries. I just can't do it remotely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247272/discussion-between-atursams-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).